# How async/await and Promise work in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, async-await

I have a small function to learn how async,await and promise workes here.

```
function delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise<void>(function(resolve) {
       setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

async function asyncAwait() {
    console.log("A");

    await delay(1000);
    console.log("B");

    await delay(1000);
    console.log("C");
}

asyncAwait();
console.log("D");
```

My understanding , the workflow would be like,

call `asyncAwait();` first, then print `A`, then wait for 1s and print `B` then wait for another 1s and print `C` at last print `D`.

but my output is like,

```
A
D
B
C
```

I don't know why `console.log("D")` is displaying second.

can anyone explain the above code ?

thanks in advance

Comment: you are not 'waiting' for the `delay` Promise and the `asyncAwait` function with Promise functionality

Comment: can you explain in details. I am new to ts

Comment: Reading time: https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8

Comment: You have the explanation in old javascript, in my answer. I have removed the promise part so is more clear to grasp. I hope it help you understand what async await really is

Comment: thanks. @DanielSan . both answers are working. but your answer is what I expected. you explained it simply. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is how asynchronous calls work.

What you think the code execution is like:

```
function delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise<void>(function(resolve) {
       setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

async function asyncAwait() {
    console.log("A");

    await delay(1000);
    console.log("B");

    await delay(1000);
    console.log("C");
}

asyncAwait();   // <-- 1st call
console.log("D");
```

Then inside that function:

```
async function asyncAwait() {
    console.log("A");  // <--- 1st print, as it is synchronous

    await delay(1000); // <--- await
    console.log("B");  // <--- 2nd print

    await delay(1000); // <-- await
    console.log("C");  // <-- 3rd print
}
```

And then finally

```
function delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise<void>(function(resolve) {
       setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

async function asyncAwait() {
    console.log("A");

    await delay(1000);
    console.log("B");

    await delay(1000);
    console.log("C");
}

asyncAwait();
console.log("D"); // <-- last print
```

**BUT,** the async function is asynchronous. So all the async calls go into the queue and are processed later.

Hence, first the synchronous calls are executed:

```
console.log("A");
console.log("D");
```

And then the async calls.

The `await` only works inside an `async` function.

So the function:

```
async function asyncFunc() {
  console.log("A");

  await delay(1000);
  console.log("B");
}
```

is roughly equivalent to this:

```
asyncFunc() {
  console.log('A');
  delay().then(()=> {
     console.log('B');
  });
}
```

So if you want the console.log("D") to be executed after the async function you should await the asyncFunction. But to use await, you have to be in a async function:

```
async function asyncFunc2() {
  await asyncAwait();
  console.log("D");
}

asyncFunc2();
```

Comment: THanks a lot for the detailed explanation. really got it

Answer (score 2):

You have to `await` for `asyncAwait()` call:

```js
function delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise<void>(function(resolve) {
       setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

async function asyncAwait() {
    console.log("A");

    await delay(1000);
    console.log("B");

    await delay(1000);
    console.log("C");
}

async function main() {
    await asyncAwait();
    console.log("D");
}

main();
```

Comment: your answer is working. but when I add one more `console.log('E');` after main();, the same doubt came. I wanted to know what happening in my code, how the flow of code . anyhow, thanks for the answer bro.

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran answer is same again. If you add `console.log('E')` and want it to be executed after `main()` has completed, then you need to say "wait for main to complete!" by calling it `await main();`

Answer (score 1):

It's behaving like that because under the hood, your code is this:

```js
function equivalentFunction() {
    console.log("A");
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            console.log("B");
            setTimeout(
                function() {
                    console.log("C");
                }
            ,1000)
        }
    ,1000)
}

equivalentFunction();
console.log("D");
```